# Extracting common sections from multiple files

Tags: include, diff, configuration-files

I have a set of configuration files for a range of devices.

They are all different, but several parts of the files are common to many (but not all) of them.

I'd like to determine all these common sections, extract each into a single file which is then "included" in the original files, so that there's only one place to edit/update.

How should I approach this? I can use `diff` or similar to find common sections among each pair of files, but I may miss things where, say, one pair has a 10 line common section, but another file shares only the first 9 lines of that - I really want to find common subsequences across as many files as possible.

There are several other questions that are somewhat related to this, but don't seem to apply to this context.